# Python re module groups match mechanism

Tags: python, regex

## Question Formation

#### background

As I am reading through the tutorial at [python2.7 redoc](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping), it introduces the behavior of the groups:

> The groups() method returns a tuple containing the strings for all the subgroups, from 1 up to however many there are.

#### question

I clearly understands how this works singly. but I can understand the following example:

```
>>> m = re.match("([abc])+","abc")
>>> m.groups()
('c',)
```

I mean, isn't `+` simply means one or more. If so, shouldn't the regex `([abc])+` = `([abc])([abc])+` (not formal BNF). Thus, the result should be:

```
('a','b','c')
```

Please shed some light about the mechanism behind, thanks.

## P.S

I want to learn the regex language interpreter, how should I start with? books or regex version, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess a picture is worth a 1000 words:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[link to the demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/W-tzjH8vg9yj76dz)

what's happening is that, as you can see on the visual representation of the automaton, your regexp is grouping over a one character one or more times until it reaches the end of the match. Then that last character gets into the group.

If you want to get the output you say, you need to do something like the following:

```
([abc])([abc])([abc])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

which will match and group one character at each position.

About documentation, I advice you to read first theory of NFA, and regexps. The MIT documentation on the topic is pretty nice:

- http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `groups` that are referred to in regex terminology are the capture groups *as defined in your regex*.

So for example, in `'([abc])+'`, there's only a single capture group, namely, `([abc])`, whereas in something like `'([abc])([xyz])+'` there are 2 groups.

So in your example, calling `.groups()` will always return a tuple of length 1 because that is how many groups exist in your regex.

The reason why it isn't returning the results you'd expect is because you're using the repeat operator `+` **outside** of the group. This ends up [causing the group to equal only the last match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), and thus only the last match (`c`) is retained. If, on the other hand, you had used `'([abc]+)'` (notice the + is *inside* the capture group), the results would have been:

```
('abc',)
```

Answer (score 0):

One pair of grouping parentheses forms one group, even if it's inside a quantifier. If a group matches multiple times due to a quantifier, only the last match for that group is saved. The group doesn't become as many groups as it had matches.